# Why won't my string update after going through a while loop?

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop

I have looked at this for a while and I can't figure out why paddedTime will not print out as "0530". I am obviously missing something. Thanks in advance!

```
public class TestString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String time = "530";
        String paddedTime = "";
        while (time.length() < 4) {
            time = "0" + time;
        }
        if (time.length() == 4) {
            time = paddedTime;
        }
        System.out.println(paddedTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning a value to `paddedTime` after the initial `""`.

Comment: did you try `paddedTime = time ;` instead of `time = paddedTime;`

Comment: Nevermind. I'm such a bonehead. It should be paddedTime = time;. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
if (time.length() == 4) {
        paddedTime = time;//to assign time value to paddedTime
    }
```

With this

```
time = paddedTime;
```

you are assigning empty string to `time`.

Answer (score 3):

You never assign a value to `paddedTime`, other than `""`. However, this should work:

```
    String time = "530";
    String paddedTime = "";
    while (time.length() < 4) {
        time = "0" + time;
    }
    if (time.length() == 4) {
        paddedTime = time;
    }
    System.out.println(paddedTime);
```